# Call lightning component from external script

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to call a function in a lightning component from an external script?

Let's say I have a standalone lightning component on a page and I want to send it a message from another script is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is obvious in an event driven frame work. Creating an event that can be triggered by the script and having a handler in the component where you want to execute the action will do the trick. You trigger a lightning event from an external script as follows:

```
        var appEvent = $A.get("e.ns:myevt");
        appEvent.setParams({        
            message: "hello world"

        });
        appEvent.fire();
```